# Displaying recyclerView on MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display my recyclerView on MainActivity, but can't seem to do it.
This is my code: (which compiles with no errors)

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_example);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getData());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Add Code to display recyclerView on Main...
}

// This is not my actual data, just testing it out
public static List<Block> getData() {
    List<Block> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] ids = {"310", "313", "320"};
    String[] names = {"name of three ten", "name of three thirteen", "name of three twenty"};
    for (int i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
        data.add(new Block(ids[i], names[i]));
    }
    return data;
}
```

And myActivity Class:

```
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

// Data: (information)
List<Block> data = new ArrayList<>();

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Block> data) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.block, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder h, int position) {
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(h.itemView);
    Block current = data.get(position);
    holder.id.setText(current.getId());
    holder.name.setText(current.getName());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView id;
    TextView name;
    Button button;

    // Constructor
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.the_course_id);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_name);
        button = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.click);

    }
}
```

}

All I'm trying to do now is that when I run the emulator, I will see the contents of the recyclerView. But, I've been stuck on this for a while as nothing seems to work.
Mind you I'm a beginner with Android, so forgive me if this is very trivial.

Comment: what does getData() return?

Comment: "I will see the contents of the recyclerView"? So what u want to do?

Comment: getData() returns a list of the Objects which I want to display on MainActivity. MyAdapter than creates a view for each of these objects. What I'm aiming for is to display a vertical list with the contents of each of these objects

Comment: show both MyAdapter class and getData function

Comment: I post an answer here that may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here you need to change the following: update -

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

to

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
```

and in adapter class change:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return data.size();
}
```

thats it. Happy coding :)

Comment: Yay!!!!!!! That fixed it. I don't understand why the setLayoutManager had to be changed, but I see that totally forgot to implement the getItemCount() method. Thank you very very much! Have a good one

Answer (score 1):

You should return the number of items in your list, within `getItemCount` as in:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

Comment: Yep. I totally forgot to implement this method. I have too much trust in Intelijj :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change `onBindViewHolder` to:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder h, int position) {
    Block current = data.get(position);
    h.id.setText(current.getId());
    h.name.setText(current.getName());

}
```

also add @SelçukCihan solution to this

**EDIT**

Also if you want to use your `MyViewHolder` you have to change the following:

First change class signature:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>
```

and also change the signature for onBindViewHolder:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder h, int position)
```

and finally change the signature of your MyViewHolder class:

```
static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

Comment: Oh thanks for bringing this up! I can't. Reason is, that RecyclerView.ViewHolder doesn't contain a field id. It is contained in the class I created MyViewHolder (which extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder). What I initially wanted to do is change the parameter of the onBindViewHolder method RecyclerView.ViewHolder to MyViewHolder, but than it changes the method signature and so the @Override cannot be applied. What can I do about it?

Comment: @JasonGreen check the EDIT part of the answer

Comment: Thank you very much. This is certainly much better. Also, may I ask why MyViewHolder class had to be declared 'static'?

Comment: @JasonGreen because it is an inner class and you need an instance of it without creating a new MyAdapter instance